# Group rows by value but only displaying the newest row in group result

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I hope I worded the title correctly, but if it is confusing I will explain what I am trying to achieve.

In my webapp users need to send a application before joining. When a user makes changes to their application rather than update the current row I have decided to insert a new row so that users can go back on past versions.

So lets say my table looks like this

```
id  |  user_id  | approved  |  timestamp
```

How can I count how many non approved applications there are without showing duplicates of user_id?

I currently have this

```
SELECT * FROM `applications` WHERE approved = 0 GROUP BY user_id
```

Now I don't know if this is even the correct way to approach this problem but after some researching online this is the best I could put together, This returns the user_id grouped but displays the oldest data from the user.

(A query to count the results or display the whole row of each unapproved users' application is what I am after)

**EDIT**

To clear things up, lets say

User 1 has edited their application 3 times. (4 rows in total)

User 2 has edited their application 2 times. (3 rows in total)

How would I get the count of unapproved applications from all users but only counting 1 ( the latest submission by timestamp) per user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  user_id,
  COUNT(user_id) total_apps, 
  SUM(case  when approved = 0 then 1 else 0 ) unapproved_apps 
FROM applications
GROUP BY user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT user_id,count(user_id),timestamp from (SELECT DISTINCT user_id, COUNT(user_id),timestamp FROM applications WHERE approved =0 ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS temp;
```

Comment: That counts all of the unapproved rows, but doesn't group the results by a user_id therefore counts duplicates. **EDIT** With your edited code it still returns the same result.

Comment: @Trendee Now?Is this what you want ?

Comment: @Trendee Sorry but I have not the actual data to test it. Try the above

Answer (score 0):

I think your way is the best way. Also you can use distinct with nested join. But if you use

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) FROM applications WHERE approved =0 ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

you would not be able to get all information of users.

Comment: That returns the count of all unapproved applications, but I need it to group the user_id as some users have more than one row

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(timestamp), COUNT(*), (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `applications` WHERE approved = 0)
FROM `applications` 
WHERE approved = 0 
GROUP BY user_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Edited out the space inbetween COUNT and (*)

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) FROM `applications` WHERE approved = 0 GROUP BY user_id HAVING COUNT(*) > ' at line 1

Comment: I suggested an edit to your post to make it work, This is along the lines of what I need. But how would I count all of the rows that are returned ( 1 per user still )

Comment: @Trendee thanks for edit, You want total row count of this result ?